# c# StreamWriter.WriteLine("string") not writing anything

Tags: c#

So I File.Create a txt and then try to write a line on it like so:

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine("string");
```

but it just skips right past it like the line doesn't exist without any messages, warnings, or errors.

Comment: could you please include more code?

Comment: Show us the full code, Check `AutoFlush` is set to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to use streamwriter.

```
using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("C:\\sample.txt", false))
{
    writetext.WriteLine("Header");
}

using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("C:\\sample.txt", true))
{
    foreach (var data in _data)
    {
        writetext.WriteLine("Sample");
    }
}
```

Notice the boolean (true or false) in the second parameter of `StreamWriter` class

```
new StreamWriter("C:\\sample.txt", true)
```

**True**: Append in file if exists

**False**: Overwrite file if exists

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a long answer and example. But when I am writing commands to my digital assistant this is how I use StreamWriter.

```
    StreamWriter sw;
    StreamReader sr;
```

then in the code you do this

```
        Settings.Default.ShellC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Commands.txt";


        scpath = Settings.Default.ShellC;



        if (!File.Exists(scpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(scpath); sw.Write("My Documents"); sw.Close(); }
```

the textbox is the ShellC design name. you would add that to your properties then, in your using statements add the properties. then if you wanted to read them back then you would use

```
StreamReader
```

and then ference the file as

```
ArrayShellCommands = File.ReadAllLines(scpath);
```